# Sending background email asynchronous still freezing the UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asynchronous

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project. I am trying to send email in background running without freezing UI. Most of the articles say now it can be done with .NET asynchronous sending email. I am sending asynchronous email but it is still freezing the UI. What I am doing is I register entering email and password then send verification email in the background. My sending email code is below.

I have interface like this.

```
public interface IMailHelper
    {
        Task SendEmailAsync(string to, string subject, string body, bool isHtml = true);
    }
```

This is the interface implementation with send-email method

```
public class MailHelper : IMailHelper
    {
        private string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        private string EmailPassword { get; set; }
        private int Port { get; set; }
        private string Host { get; set; }

        public MailHelper()
        {
            this.EmailAddress = AppConfig.SystemEmailAddress;
            this.EmailPassword = AppConfig.SystemEmailPassword;
            this.Port = AppConfig.SystemMailPort;
            this.Host = AppConfig.SystemMailHost;
        }

        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string to, string subject, string body, bool isHtml = true)
        {
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(to);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(this.EmailAddress);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = this.EmailAddress,
                    Password = this.EmailPassword
                };
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = this.Host;
                smtp.Port = this.Port;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am sending asynchronous email.

This is my action method in controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    //[AngularValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Do other stuffs here
            await  _mailHelper.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, AppConfig.AccountVerifyMailSubject, WebHelper.BuildAccountVerificationEmailBody(user.UserName, verificationUrl));
        }
        // Do other stuffs here
    }
```

As you can see I am trying to send email in background in the action method. My code is sending email successfully. But I am sure it is freezing the UI because it take longer than it should be. I tested many times. Not different with sending email normally. Why it is freezing the UI? My code is not sending background email in new process.

Comment: Running async doesn't mean running in the background, that's not how it works. Your action still won't return until the mali task has completed. IF you want to send mail in the background, you need to look at another method. For example, something like Hangfire for kicking off background tasks.

Comment: Ohh. So SendAsync is not for sending in background for sure? So please can I have a link for the best and simple tutorial for sending email in background please?

Comment: I have [a short blog post](https://contrivedexample.com/2016/11/05/upgrade-your-butler-to-async/) explaining the most basic case of using async.

Comment: Use task/thread for sending e-mails? That way the UI wont freeze.

Comment: Please @Verkade89 can I have link sending email in background running new Thread? I tried it once before and it was not working. That is why.

Comment: Don't use `Task.Run` to do anything in asp.net. You should hand off such tasks in a distributed manner, like to a queue, but if you must do "fire and forget" then there are some options: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html

Comment: Thanks so much @Crowcoder. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Most of the articles say now it can be done with .NET asynchronous sending email.

Those articles are all wrong, sorry.

I have a blog post that goes into [various implementations of ASP.NET background tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). In summary, if you **don't care** that emails are occasionally lost, then you can just use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<JsonResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ...
    HostingEnvironment.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        _mailHelper.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, AppConfig.AccountVerifyMailSubject, WebHelper.BuildAccountVerificationEmailBody(user.UserName, verificationUrl));
  }
  ...
}
```

If you **do care** that emails are not lost, then you'll have to place them in some sort of reliable queue (Azure Queue, or MSMQ) and have an independent background worker send the actual email (Azure Function / WebJob / Worker Role, or Win32 service).

Comment: Thank u. Thanks for support. I have been reading ur article. Articles should not assure that it can be done using async task.